# Question about covariant derivative on manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am currently learning about the covariant derivative on smooth manifolds with the following definition:

> **Definition.** A covariant derivative of vector fields is an operation that associates to two vector fields $X$ and $Y$ a new vector field $\nabla_XY$ and satisfies the following properties.
>
> 1. $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$-linearity with respect to $X$:
>    $$
>    \nabla_{X_1+X_2}Y = \nabla_{X_1}Y + \nabla_{X_2}Y,\quad \nabla_{fX}Y = f\nabla_XY;
>    $$
> 2. additivity and the Leibniz rule with respect to $Y$:
>    $$
>    \nabla_X(Y_1+y_2) = \nabla_XY_1+\nabla_XY_2,\quad \nabla_X(fY) = D_Xf\cdot Y + f\nabla_XY.
>    $$

Then there is this theorem, for which I do not understand the proof. [image]

How am I supposed to understand the transfer the vectorfield via $\varphi$ part? Where does the covariant derivative on $U_i$ come from? Can you please explain me, what the first part with the chart means in exact terms? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the author means that $\nabla^i$ is the pullback through $\varphi_i$ of the covariant derivative $\bar \nabla$ on $\Bbb R^n$ defined by taking the directional derivatives in the following way.
If $\bar X= \sum_j \bar X^j\partial_j$ and $\bar Y = \sum_k \bar Y^k \partial_k$ are vectors fields on $\Bbb R^n$, then $\bar \nabla_{\bar X} \bar Y = \sum_{j,k} \bar X^j \frac{\partial \bar Y^k}{\partial x^j} \partial_k$.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be vector fields on $M$.
The pullback covariant derivative $\nabla^i = {\varphi_i}^*\bar\nabla$ is given by the formula $\nabla^i_XY= {\varphi_i}^*\left(\bar \nabla_{{\varphi_i}_*X}{\varphi_i}_*Y\right)$, and therefore, the covariant derivative $\nabla$ on $M$ is given by

$$
\nabla_XY = \left(\sum_i\lambda_i\nabla^i\right)_XY= \sum_i\lambda_i {\varphi_i}^*\left(\bar\nabla_{{\varphi_i}_*X}{\varphi_i}_*Y\right).
$$
You can check that it indeed defines a covariant derivative since the pullback $\varphi_i^*$ and the pushforward ${\varphi_i}_*$ are $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M;\Bbb R)$-linear.

In addition, I would like to say that this construction works on all manifolds, not only compact ones (as suggests the text OP has linked).
Indeed, we only need to have a partition of unity associated to a locally finite open cover.
Since all manifolds possess such a partition of unity, the same proof works.

Finally, let us mention that there is a quicker but more conceptual way to prove the existence of a covariant derivative on any manifold.
By the Whitney's embedding Theorem, any manifold embeds into some euclidean space $\Bbb R^N$.
The orthogonal projection of the directional derivative of vector fields on the tangent space yields such a covariant derivative.
It is the famous Levi-Civita connection, which is in fact associated to the Riemannian metric induced by the embedding.

---

In case your question is more about the definition of the pushforward or the pullback through a diffeomorphism $\varphi\colon U\to V$, they are defined by
$$
(\varphi_*X)(q) = d\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(q)) X(\varphi^{-1}(q))
$$
for $q\in V$ and $X$ a vector field on $U$, and
$$
(\varphi^* Y)(p) = [d\varphi(p)]^{-1} Y(\varphi(p))
$$
for $p\in U$ and $Y$ a vector field on $V$.

Comment: So $\bar{X}$ is a Vector field in $\mathbb{R}^n$ right? What do you mean with $\partial_i$?

Comment: What is the covariant derivative on $\mathbb{R}^n$? I know this for surfaces, by taking the tangential part of the directional derivative, but in $\mathbb{R}^n$ everything is tangent to this seems odd

Comment: @QED Yes, $\bar X$ is a vector field on $\Bbb R^n$. $\partial_i$ is the $i$th vector of the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^n$, this is standard notation in geometry. If you read carefully what I wrote, you will see that I have already defined the covariant derivative $\bar \nabla$ on $\Bbb R^n$. The one for surfaces you know is the Levi-Civita connection for embedded surfaces which is just a particular case. Here you are studying the full generality apparently.

Comment: But what is the product $\partial_i \partial_j$?

Comment: @QED I have ever written such a thing, did I?

Comment: Ah I see, you changed it now. Thank you for the clear answer

Comment: @QED Yes. $X^i$ is a function, $Y^j$ also, $\partial_i Y^j$ is its $i$th partial derivative, and you have the right to take their product. I have edited it to make it clearer that $\partial_iY^j$ is a partial derivative of a function